# DataTables localeCompare sorting, can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm not a programmer but I can put some code together to make it work. I'm struggling wit this one for hours. I've got a problem with sorting non-ascii characters in DataTables jQuery plugin. Found code on DataTables website that should make it work. But it does not. I'd be grateful for helping me debug. I've put this code in header:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"polish-string-asc" : function (s1, s2) {
    return s1.localeCompare(s2);
},

"polish-string-desc" : function (s1, s2) {
    return s2.localeCompare(s1);
}
} );
```

and this is how I run tables:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
      "autoWidth": false,
      "columns": [
null,
null,
{ "orderable": false },
{ "orderable": false }
  ],
columnDefs: [
{ type: 'polish-string', targets: 1 }
  ],
});
});
```

Script works fine with default sorting. Problem is it does not work with this sorting plugin.

I'm using DataTables in WordPress.

Chrome gives me this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oSort' of undefined".

FireFox gives me this: "TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTableExt is undefined".

Please please help me debug this one. Thank you.

Comment: Check if datatable scripts are loaded before the script where above code is in or try to get a jsfiddle example with problem.

Comment: It looks like it works here http://jsfiddle.net/rt9ftxo8/11/ but not on my Wordpress page. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Bla - "_What could be the problem_?" that the fiddle encapsulating the script in `onload`, while your wordpress fires it off as soon as the code is reached. Wrap it into a `$(document).ready(function() { ..]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables script was in footer. It should be loaded first.

href tags inside td were messing up. Removing href helped. Thanks for hints.